# Python trying to print results as menu

Tags: python

Hi this is what I so far

```
COLS= int(input("Number of Students to enter: "))
ROWS= int(input("Number of Grades per student: "))


number =[]

for c in range(COLS):
   grades = []
   student =(input("Enter Student ID number "))
   number.append(student)
   number.append(grades)


   count = 1        
   for r in range (ROWS):
      grade = (input("Enter Grade for Module "+str(count)+ ": "))
      grades.append(grade)
      count = count + 1

print
print (number)
print
print ('Rows and Columns')

print (student) + (grades)
```

everything up to `count = count + 1`  i am happy with. But i am unsure how to print the results like

```
    Rows and Columns
    123 88 97 66 52
    124 77 64 73 65
```

^^^
that would be the "menu" if the input was

```
No of Students:2
No of grades: 4
student no.= 123
Grade 1 = 88
Grade 2= 97 
Grade 3 = 66
Grade 4 = 52
```

.
and the the next line of the menu would be the other students input. 
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is not the best choice, however ...:

```
for i in range(len(number)):
    # if this element is an int, then following would be the list of grades.
    if isinstance(number[i],str):
        print(number[i],' '.join(map(str, number[i+1])))
```

Comment: I know im just starting to learn. But your code isnt working with mine, it isnt printing anything after "Rows and columns"

Comment: Are you using python3?